# How to make inet_server_addr() return localhost in spite of ::1/128

Tags: postgresql

How to make inet_server_addr() return an name as IPv4?

Comment: Do you want to it to return 'localhost' or an IPv4 address?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. What's `listen_addresses` set to? What do you mean by *in spite of ::1/128*? What's the actual return value you want?

Comment: I got answer on manual. inet is a type on postgres. To convert it to text must invoke host( inet_server_addr() ) to cast it to varchar. Without it has returned that weird ::1/128 token.

Answer (score 1):

@cavila's answer in comments also answers the question "Why does `select inet_server_addr() || ''` return a result like 192.168.44.195**/32**?"

[inet](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-net-types.html) is a data type. To suppress the number of bits and get a text IP like '192.168.51.195', use `select(host(inet_server_addr()))`.